# How can I diagnose an AWS EC2 instance that is failing to start from a snapshot?

Tags: amazon-ec2, ubuntu-18.04

I run a simple Ubuntu 18 / Postgresql / Django server on an EC2 instance. It worked flawlessly for 21 months, then suddenly stopped on 26th December at around 6:30am GMT. From the status checks, the host is fine but the container cannot be reached.

The only error in the logs revealed by instance -> Monitor and Troubleshoot -> Get System Log is `Failed to start Service for snap apâ€¦amazon-ssm-agent.amazon-ssm-agent` (fuller trace below). I have tried SSH from my machine and from within the AWS console. (The serial tty interface is possible if the machine is based on the AWS Nitro system, and when I try to connect AWS reports it is not.)

I have made a volume from a snapshot and examined it from another instance. The database files are fine, file system seem OK, there's a gigabyte free. I know these wouldn't prevent SSH, but where might I find any clues as to what is preventing it running? Can I roll back any recent SSM Agent updates?

```
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started ebtables ruleset management.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target Network (Pre).
         Starting Network Service...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Create Volatile Files and Directories.
         Starting Update UTMP about System Boot/Shutdown...
         Starting Network Time Synchronization...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Update UTMP about System Boot/Shutdown.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Network Service.
         Starting Network Name Resolution...
         Starting Wait for Network to be Configured...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Wait for Network to be Configured.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Network Time Synchronization.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target System Time Synchronized.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target System Initialization.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Daily apt download activities.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Discard unused blocks once a week.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Listening on D-Bus System Message Bus Socket.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Listening on Open-iSCSI iscsid Socket.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Run certbot twice daily.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Message of the Day.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Listening on gunicorn socket.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Listening on UUID daemon activation socket.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Daily Cleanup of Temporary Directories.
         Starting LXD - unix socket.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Listening on ACPID Listen Socket.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started ACPI Events Check.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target Paths.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Daily apt upgrade and clean activities.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target Timers.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Network Name Resolution.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Listening on LXD - unix socket.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target Sockets.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target Basic System.
         Starting LSB: Record successful boot for GRUB...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started ACPI event daemon.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Deferred execution scheduler.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started D-Bus System Message Bus.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started FUSE filesystem for LXC.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Regular background program processing daemon.
         Starting Resets System Activity Data Collector...
         Starting Login Service...
         Starting System Logging Service...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started irqbalance daemon.
         Starting LXD - container startup/shutdown...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target Host and Network Name Lookups.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target Network.
         Starting A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Service for snap applicatioâ€¦amazon-ssm-agent.amazon-ssm-agent.
         Starting PostgreSQL Cluster 11-main...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target Network is Online.
         Starting Availability of block devices...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target Remote File Systems (Pre).
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target Remote File Systems.
         Starting LSB: automatic crash report generation...
         Starting Permit User Sessions...
         Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started System Logging Service.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Resets System Activity Data Collector.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Availability of block devices.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started LSB: automatic crash report generation.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Permit User Sessions.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Login Service.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Unattended Upgrades Shutdown.
         Starting Hold until boot process finishes up...
         Starting Terminate Plymouth Boot Screen...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started LSB: Record successful boot for GRUB.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Hold until boot process finishes up.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Terminate Plymouth Boot Screen.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Stopped Service for snap applicatioâ€¦amazon-ssm-agent.amazon-ssm-agent.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Service for snap applicatioâ€¦amazon-ssm-agent.amazon-ssm-agent.
         Starting Set console scheme...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Set console scheme.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Created slice system-getty.slice.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Getty on tty1.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started LXD - container startup/shutdown.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Stopped Service for snap applicatioâ€¦amazon-ssm-agent.amazon-ssm-agent.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Service for snap applicatioâ€¦amazon-ssm-agent.amazon-ssm-agent.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Stopped Service for snap applicatioâ€¦amazon-ssm-agent.amazon-ssm-agent.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Service for snap applicatioâ€¦amazon-ssm-agent.amazon-ssm-agent.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Found device /dev/ttyS0.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Serial Getty on ttyS0.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target Login Prompts.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Listening on Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status /dev/rfkill Watch.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Stopped Service for snap applicatioâ€¦amazon-ssm-agent.amazon-ssm-agent.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Service for snap applicatioâ€¦amazon-ssm-agent.amazon-ssm-agent.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Stopped Service for snap applicatioâ€¦amazon-ssm-agent.amazon-ssm-agent.
[[0;1;31mFAILED[0m] Failed to start Service for snap apâ€¦amazon-ssm-agent.amazon-ssm-agent.
See 'systemctl status snap.amazon-ssm-aâ€¦.amazon-ssm-agent.service' for details.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started PostgreSQL Cluster 11-main.
         Starting PostgreSQL RDBMS...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started PostgreSQL RDBMS.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target Multi-User System.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target Graphical Interface.
         Starting Update UTMP about System Runlevel Changes...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Update UTMP about System Runlevel Changes.


Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS ip-172-31-42-17 ttyS0

ip-172-31-42-17 login: [[0;32m  OK  [0m] Stopped target Timers.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Stopped Daily Cleanup of Temporary Directories.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Closed Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status /dev/rfkill Watch.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Stopped target Host and Network Name Lookups.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Stopped Daily apt upgrade and clean activities.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Stopped Daily apt download activities.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Stopped Message of the Day.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Stopped target Network is Online.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Stopped Discard unused blocks once a week.
         Stopping ACPI event daemon...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Stopped Run certbot twice daily.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Stopped target System Time Synchronized.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Stopped Wait for Network to be Configured.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Stopped target Graphical Interface.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Stopped target Multi-User System.
         Stopping LSB: Record successful boot for GRUB...
         Stopping FUSE filesystem for LXC...
         Stopping LSB: automatic crash report generation...
         Stopping A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
         Unmounting Mount unit for amazon-ssm-agent, revision 1480...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Stopped target Login Prompts.
         Stopping Serial Getty on ttyS0...
         Stopping Getty on tty1...
         Stopping OpenBSD Secure Shell server...
         Stopping D-Bus System Message Bus...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Stopped PostgreSQL RDBMS.
         Stopping PostgreSQL Cluster 11-main...
         Unmounting Mount unit for amazon-ssm-agent, revision 1566...
         Stopping Deferred execution scheduler...
         Stopping Regular background program processing daemon...
         Stopping System Logging Service...
         Unmounting Mount unit for core, revision 8935...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Stopped Resets System Activity Data Collector.
         Stopping LXD - container startup/shutdown...
         Stopping Unattended Upgrades Shutdown...
         Unmounting Mount unit for core, revision 8268...
         Stopping Availability of block devices...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Unmounted /var/lib/lxcfs.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Stopped ACPI event daemon.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Stopped Deferred execution scheduler.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Stopped Regular background program processing daemon.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Stopped System Logging Service.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Stopped Unattended Upgrades Shutdown.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Stopped OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Stopped Getty on tty1.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Stopped Serial Getty on ttyS0.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Stopped LSB: automatic crash report generation.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Stopped A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Unmounted Mount unit for amazon-ssm-agent, revision 1480.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Stopped D-Bus System Message Bus.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Stopped PostgreSQL Cluster 11-main.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Unmounted Mount unit for amazon-ssm-agent, revision 1566.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Unmounted Mount unit for core, revision 8935.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Unmounted Mount unit for core, revision 8268.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Stopped Availability of block devices.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Stopped FUSE filesystem for LXC.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Removed slice system-postgresql.slice.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Removed slice system-serial\x2dgetty.slice.
         Stopping Permit User Sessions...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Removed slice system-getty.slice.
         Stopping Login Service...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target Unmount All Filesystems.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Stopped Login Service.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Stopped Permit User Sessions.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Stopped target Remote File Systems.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Stopped target Remote File Systems (Pre).
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Stopped target Network.
         Stopping Network Name Resolution...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Stopped Network Name Resolution.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Stopped LSB: Record successful boot for GRUB.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Stopped LXD - container startup/shutdown.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Stopped target Basic System.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Stopped target Slices.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Removed slice User and Session Slice.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Stopped target Sockets.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Closed LXD - unix socket.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Closed UUID daemon activation socket.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Closed ACPID Listen Socket.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Closed Open-iSCSI iscsid Socket.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Closed Syslog Socket.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Closed D-Bus System Message Bus Socket.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Closed gunicorn socket.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Stopped target Paths.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Stopped ACPI Events Check.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Stopped target System Initialization.
         Stopping Update UTMP about System Boot/Shutdown...
         Stopping Network Time Synchronization...
         Stopping Load/Save Random Seed...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Stopped target Swap.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Stopped target Local Encrypted Volumes.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Stopped Forward Password Requests to Wall Directory Watch.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Stopped Dispatch Password Requests to Console Directory Watch.
         Stopping Network Service...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Stopped Network Service.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Stopped Network Time Synchronization.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Stopped Load/Save Random Seed.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Stopped target Network (Pre).
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Stopped Apply Kernel Variables.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Stopped Load Kernel Modules.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Stopped Update UTMP about System Boot/Shutdown.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Stopped Create Volatile Files and Directories.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Stopped target Local File Systems.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Stopped target Local File Systems (Pre).
         Stopping Monitoring of LVM2 mirrorsâ€¦ng dmeventd or progress polling...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Stopped Create Static Device Nodes in /dev.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Stopped Remount Root and Kernel File Systems.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target Shutdown.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target Final Step.
         Starting Reboot...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Stopped Monitoring of LVM2 mirrors,â€¦sing dmeventd or progress polling.
         Stopping LVM2 metadata daemon...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Stopped LVM2 metadata daemon.
[ 4216.525640] reboot: Restarting system
[    3.109586] x86/mm: Checked W+X mappings: passed, no W+X pages found.
[    3.115419] x86/mm: Checking user space page tables
[    3.129304] x86/mm: Checked W+X mappings: passed, no W+X pages found.
[    3.134578] Run /init as init process
[    3.137677] tsc: Refined TSC clocksource calibration: 2400.001 MHz
[    3.142636] clocksource: tsc: mask: 0xffffffffffffffff max_cycles: 0x22983858435, max_idle_ns: 440795258295 ns
Loading, please wait...
starting version 237
[    3.364938] xen_netfront: Initialising Xen virtual ethernet driver
[    3.386430] cryptd: max_cpu_qlen set to 1000
[    3.430248] AVX2 version of gcm_enc/dec engaged.
[    3.435444] AES CTR mode by8 optimization enabled
Begin: Loading essential drivers ... [    5.245535] raid6: avx2x4   gen() 23272 MB/s
[    5.297534] raid6: avx2x4   xor() 14187 MB/s
[    5.349534] raid6: avx2x2   gen() 20031 MB/s
[    5.401536] raid6: avx2x2   xor() 12647 MB/s
[    5.453535] raid6: avx2x1   gen() 17305 MB/s
[    5.505539] raid6: avx2x1   xor() 11852 MB/s
[    5.557538] raid6: sse2x4   gen() 12631 MB/s
[    5.609534] raid6: sse2x4   xor()  8024 MB/s
[    5.661535] raid6: sse2x2   gen() 10619 MB/s
[    5.713537] raid6: sse2x2   xor()  7029 MB/s
[    5.765540] raid6: sse2x1   gen()  9011 MB/s
[    5.813534] raid6: sse2x1   xor()  6511 MB/s
[    5.817872] raid6: using algorithm avx2x4 gen() 23272 MB/s
[    5.823964] raid6: .... xor() 14187 MB/s, rmw enabled
[    5.829442] raid6: using avx2x2 recovery algorithm
[    5.836630] xor: automatically using best checksumming function   avx       
[    5.845368] async_tx: api initialized (async)
done.
Begin: Running /scripts/init-premount ... done.
Begin: Mounting root file system ... Begin: Running /scripts/local-top ... done.
Begin: Running /scripts/local-premount ... [    5.915807] Btrfs loaded, crc32c=crc32c-intel
Scanning for Btrfs filesystems
done.
Warning: fsck not present, so skipping root file system
[    5.949305] EXT4-fs (xvda1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
done.
Begin: Running /scripts/local-bottom ... done.
Begin: Running /scripts/init-bottom ... /scripts/init-bottom/plymouth: line 18: /bin/plymouth: not found
done.
[    6.200940] systemd[1]: systemd 237 running in system mode. (+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA +APPARMOR +SMACK +SYSVINIT +UTMP +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ +LZ4 +SECCOMP +BLKID +ELFUTILS +KMOD -IDN2 +IDN -PCRE2 default-hierarchy=hybrid)
[    6.225302] systemd[1]: Detected virtualization xen.
[    6.231580] systemd[1]: Detected architecture x86-64.

Welcome to [1mUbuntu 18.04.4 LTS[0m!

[    6.245592] systemd[1]: Set hostname to <ip-172-31-42-17>.
[    6.441761] systemd[1]: Created slice User and Session Slice.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Created slice User and Session Slice.
[    6.455437] systemd[1]: Started Forward Password Requests to Wall Directory Watch.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Forward Password Requests to Wall Directory Watch.
[    6.473066] systemd[1]: Created slice System Slice.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Created slice System Slice.
[    6.480819] systemd[1]: Listening on Network Service Netlink Socket.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Listening on Network Service Netlink Socket.
[    6.490459] systemd[1]: Listening on Journal Audit Socket.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Listening on Journal Audit Socket.
[    6.499062] systemd[1]: Reached target Slices.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target Slices.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Listening on Journal Socket (/dev/log).
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Listening on Journal Socket.
         Starting Set the console keyboard layout...
         Starting Create list of required stâ€¦ce nodes for the current kernel...
         Mounting Kernel Debug File System...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Listening on Device-mapper event daemon FIFOs.
         Starting Remount Root and Kernel File Systems...
         Mounting POSIX Message Queue File System...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Listening on LVM2 poll daemon socket.
[    6.582472] EXT4-fs (xvda1): re-mounted. Opts: discard
         Starting Load Kernel Modules...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Listening on udev Control Socket.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Listening on /dev/initctl Compatibility Named Pipe.
[    6.623171] Loading iSCSI transport class v2.0-870.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Created slice system-serial\x2dgetty.slice.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Listening on Syslog Socket.
         Starting Journal Service...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Listening on udev Kernel Socket.
         Starting udev Coldplug all Devices...
         Mounting Huge Pages File System...
[    6.680968] iscsi: registered transport (tcp)
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Set up automount Arbitrary Executabâ€¦rmats File System Automount Point.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target Swap.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Listening on LVM2 metadata daemon socket.
         Starting Monitoring of LVM2 mirrorsâ€¦ng dmeventd or progress polling...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Created slice system-postgresql.slice.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Create list of required staâ€¦vice nodes for the current kernel.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Mounted Kernel Debug File System.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Remount Root and Kernel File Systems.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Mounted POSIX Message Queue File System.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Mounted Huge Pages File System.
         Starting Load/Save Random Seed...
         Starting Create Static Device Nodes in /dev...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started LVM2 metadata daemon.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Load/Save Random Seed.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Monitoring of LVM2 mirrors,â€¦sing dmeventd or progress polling.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Create Static Device Nodes in /dev.
         Starting udev Kernel Device Manager...
[    6.858160] iscsi: registered transport (iser)
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Load Kernel Modules.
         Mounting Kernel Configuration File System...
         Mounting FUSE Control File System...
         Starting Apply Kernel Variables...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Journal Service.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Mounted Kernel Configuration File System.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Mounted FUSE Control File System.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started udev Kernel Device Manager.
         Starting Flush Journal to Persistent Storage...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Apply Kernel Variables.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Set the console keyboard layout.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target Local File Systems (Pre).
         Mounting Mount unit for amazon-ssm-agent, revision 1480...
         Mounting Mount unit for core, revision 8268...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target Local File Systems.
         Starting Tell Plymouth To Write Out Runtime Data...
         Starting ebtables ruleset management...
         Starting Set console font and keymap...
         Mounting Mount unit for amazon-ssm-agent, revision 1566...
         Mounting Mount unit for core, revision 8935...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Mounted Mount unit for amazon-ssm-agent, revision 1480.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Mounted Mount unit for core, revision 8268.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Tell Plymouth To Write Out Runtime Data.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Set console font and keymap.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Mounted Mount unit for amazon-ssm-agent, revision 1566.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Mounted Mount unit for core, revision 8935.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started ebtables ruleset management.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target Network (Pre).
         Starting Network Service...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started udev Coldplug all Devices.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Dispatch Password Requests to Console Directory Watch.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target Local Encrypted Volumes.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Network Service.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Flush Journal to Persistent Storage.
         Starting Create Volatile Files and Directories...
         Starting Wait for Network to be Configured...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Create Volatile Files and Directories.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Wait for Network to be Configured.
         Starting Update UTMP about System Boot/Shutdown...
         Starting Network Time Synchronization...
         Starting Network Name Resolution...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Update UTMP about System Boot/Shutdown.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Network Time Synchronization.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Network Name Resolution.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target Network.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target Network is Online.
         Starting Availability of block devices...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target Remote File Systems (Pre).
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target Remote File Systems.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target Host and Network Name Lookups.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target System Initialization.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Listening on gunicorn socket.
         Starting LXD - unix socket.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Listening on UUID daemon activation socket.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Listening on ACPID Listen Socket.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Daily Cleanup of Temporary Directories.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Listening on Open-iSCSI iscsid Socket.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Listening on D-Bus System Message Bus Socket.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started ACPI Events Check.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target Paths.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target System Time Synchronized.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Daily apt download activities.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Discard unused blocks once a week.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Run certbot twice daily.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Message of the Day.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Daily apt upgrade and clean activities.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target Timers.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Availability of block devices.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Listening on LXD - unix socket.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target Sockets.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target Basic System.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started ACPI event daemon.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Regular background program processing daemon.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started FUSE filesystem for LXC.
         Starting LXD - container startup/shutdown...
         Starting System Logging Service...
         Starting PostgreSQL Cluster 11-main...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Service for snap applicatioâ€¦amazon-ssm-agent.amazon-ssm-agent.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Deferred execution scheduler.
         Starting Permit User Sessions...
         Starting A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
         Starting LSB: automatic crash report generation...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started irqbalance daemon.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started D-Bus System Message Bus.
         Starting LSB: Record successful boot for GRUB...
         Starting Login Service...
         Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server...
         Starting Resets System Activity Data Collector...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started System Logging Service.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Permit User Sessions.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started LSB: automatic crash report generation.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Resets System Activity Data Collector.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Login Service.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Unattended Upgrades Shutdown.
         Starting Terminate Plymouth Boot Screen...
         Starting Hold until boot process finishes up...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Terminate Plymouth Boot Screen.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started LSB: Record successful boot for GRUB.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Hold until boot process finishes up.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Stopped Service for snap applicatioâ€¦amazon-ssm-agent.amazon-ssm-agent.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Service for snap applicatioâ€¦amazon-ssm-agent.amazon-ssm-agent.
         Starting Set console scheme...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started LXD - container startup/shutdown.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Set console scheme.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Created slice system-getty.slice.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Getty on tty1.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Stopped Service for snap applicatioâ€¦amazon-ssm-agent.amazon-ssm-agent.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Service for snap applicatioâ€¦amazon-ssm-agent.amazon-ssm-agent.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Found device /dev/ttyS0.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Serial Getty on ttyS0.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target Login Prompts.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Stopped Service for snap applicatioâ€¦amazon-ssm-agent.amazon-ssm-agent.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Service for snap applicatioâ€¦amazon-ssm-agent.amazon-ssm-agent.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Listening on Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status /dev/rfkill Watch.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Stopped Service for snap applicatioâ€¦amazon-ssm-agent.amazon-ssm-agent.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Service for snap applicatioâ€¦amazon-ssm-agent.amazon-ssm-agent.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Stopped Service for snap applicatioâ€¦amazon-ssm-agent.amazon-ssm-agent.
[[0;1;31mFAILED[0m] Failed to start Service for snap apâ€¦amazon-ssm-agent.amazon-ssm-agent.
See 'systemctl status snap.amazon-ssm-aâ€¦.amazon-ssm-agent.service' for details.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started PostgreSQL Cluster 11-main.
         Starting PostgreSQL RDBMS...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started PostgreSQL RDBMS.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target Multi-User System.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target Graphical Interface.
         Starting Update UTMP about System Runlevel Changes...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Update UTMP about System Runlevel Changes.
Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS ip-172-31-42-17 ttyS0
ip-172-31-42-17 login:
```

Comment: AWS Nitro is a virtualization hardware/hypervisor, if you are using a [recent instance type](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instance-types.html) then your Ubuntu is running on AWS Nitro and you can use EC2 serial console.

Comment: Thanks very much for the info. AWS reports "This instance type is not supported for the EC2 serial console." so I assume mine isn't recent enough or Nitro-equipped.

Comment: What kind of error do you get when you try to `ssh`? Check `/var/log` in the mounted volume for any related errors.

Comment: When I try to connect SSH times out, and AWS in-browser connect never manages to start "We were unable to connect to your instance. Make sure that your instance’s network settings are configured correctly for EC2 Instance Connect.".

Comment: I have posted a separate question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70521399/aws-ec2-error-you-might-have-to-change-the-root-device-from-dev-hda-d-to-de) as this one is answered.

Comment: I got the same issue. It is 24 hours now trying to configure the server